# What is the SMBus I2C Header on my motherboard?

Tags: supermicro

My motherboard has a slot on the motherboard for,

> JPI2C1 Power Supply SMBus I2C Header (X13SAE-F only)

What is this used for? The [motherboard manual](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/X13/MNL-2425.pdf) say nothing more about it. What is this for? What do I plug in there? What happens if I plug nothing in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *system management* I²C bus is used for various purposes, most commonly:

- access DIMM SPD memory
- access sensor information - temperature levels, fan speeds, voltage levels
- control fan speeds
- smart power-supply management (fan/temperature/voltages)

There may be vendor options that connect to the I²C header - either additional monitor/actor chips (case temperature sensors, smart PSU monitoring), or optional monitoring or management like IPMI / lights-out management. There may also be third-party options that you can plug in and use. There's no need to plug in anything though.

Workstation and server boards may use multiple I²C busses.

Comment: doesn't answer What do I plug in there? What happens if I plug nothing in there?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I thought it became rather obvious - I've added some text just for you. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure how it's obvious when something says "Power Supply SMBus" I think it needs power and I'm wondering what kind of power I need to provide it. But thanks.

Comment: My educated guess is that you can plug in a management cable to a smart power supply to monitor voltages, temperature or fan speed. Perhaps even for a redundant PSU.

Comment: If so, that information would make for a better answer.